# How to consume/chain functions "Pythonically"?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, function-composition

I have a set of functions `f(x), g(x), s(x), t(x)`.

They are designed to be chained together like this: `f(g(s(t(x))))`

The functions are designed so they can be chained in any sequence. Another part of my code builds the sequence in a list: `[f, g, s, t]`

Is there an *elegant* way to take the list and chain the function calls, getting the output of the last result?

Now obviously I can do it using an outside counter-like variable which tracks the output and a simple `for` loop increment index, but I was wondering if there is an more Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37450089/355230) of mine (or one of the others) to the question [Assign multiple functions to a single variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449945/assign-multiple-functions-to-a-single-variable) might help.

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of  "elegant", and FWIW, the most pythonic solution is to use an explicit for loop (it's the simple, no-brainer, obvious, readable and easy to debug and maintain solution) hich might not be what you'd find the most "elegant".

Comment: [Apply-a-list-of-python-functions-in-order-elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123375/apply-a-list-of-python-functions-in-order-elegantly)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduce is the perfect answer (though we need to start with the innermost function, thus `reversed`):

```
import functools

functions = [f, g, s, t]
y = functools.reduce(lambda a, f: f(a), reversed(functions), x)
```

EDIT: With constant parameters, as easy as this:

```
p1, p2 = 5, 42
y = functools.reduce(lambda a, f: f(a, p1, p2), reversed(functions), x)
```

Comment: Great answer! Is it possible for functions with multiple inputs I'm wondering? like f(x, a, b). a and b being constants?

Comment: Nvm, figured it out! I can use lamda a,b,c,f

Answer (score 3):

Martineau and Amadan already posted the "elegant" solution. Now the truly pythonic solution is as stupid, simple an plain boring as it can get:

```
def chain(arg, *funcs):
    # chain(42, f, g, s) => f(g(s(42)))
    result = arg
    for func in reversed(funcs):
        result = func(result)
    return result
```

It's clearly *not* what most people would consider "elegant", but it's perfectly obvious, readable, and is very easy to trace and debug - and that's what matters most wrt/ python's philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming, this operation is called function composition. Python doesn't have a compose function in the standard library, but it's fairly easy to write yourself:

```
from functools import partial
# additional import for python 3: from itertools import reduce
def compose(*args):
    return partial(reduce, lambda x, y: y(x), reversed(args))
```

you can then compose functions like so

```
fgst_x = compose(f, g, s, t)(x)
```

or

```
funcs = [f, g, s, t]
fgst = compose(*funcs)
fgst_x = fgst(x)
```